# Check a list of bluetooth MAC Addresses if they are in range

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

There are a few linux projects to detect if a bluetooth device is in range and perform an action. ie when you get near your house, turn on the lights. When the wife gets home, turn on some funky music.

I wish to monitor 20+ devices to see if they get in range, ie when vehicles with bluetooth radios arrive, record the time and perform an action.

The fastest time is:

```
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# time hcitool name XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
 RADIO 39
 real    0m2.686s
```

If the device can't be found:

```
# Device doesn't exist
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# time hcitool name XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
real    0m5.141s
```

So 20 devices x 5 seconds = 100 Seconds per sweep of MAC Addresses.

Does anyone know if I can parallel a ping/hcitool request? Asking the name or l2ping multiple MAC Addresses?